# Getting snake lower case using sed

Tags: sed

If I have somethign like 
`{
  "name" : "MyNameIsKhan"
  "symbol": "MyNameIsKhan"
}`

I want to convert this to 
`{
  "name" : "MyNameIsKhan"
  "symbol": "my_name_is_khan"
}`

sed -e 's/([A-Z])/_\L\1/g' -e 's/^-//'

however missing something as it is also changing other name field.
PS- dont want to change name and symbol may have any number of space. Also fine if possible with awk..??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

give this sed one-liner a try:

```
sed '/"symbol"/s/[A-Z]/_\l&/g;s/"_/"/' file
```

Test:

```
kent$  cat f
{
  "name" : "MyNameIsKhan"
  "symbol": "MyNameIsKhan"
}
kent$  sed  '/"symbol"/s/[A-Z]/_\l&/g;s/"_/"/' f
{
  "name" : "MyNameIsKhan"
  "symbol": "my_name_is_khan"
}
```

Comment: Worked like charm :)

Answer (score 0):

this may help you:

```
sed -r 's/([a-z]+)([A-Z][a-z]+)/\1_\l\2/g'
```

Comment: how will it only work for symbols and not for name field ? Also not working for first letter... :(

Comment: Please add some commentary to described why this solves the problem.

Comment: Although this code may help to solve the problem, providing
additional context regarding _why_ and/or _how_ it answers
the question would significantly improve its long-term
value.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ sed -r '/symbol/ {s/([a-z])([A-Z])/\1_\L\2/g; s/: "[A-Z]/\L\0/}' test.txt
{
  "name" : "MyNameIsKhan"
  "symbol": "my_name_is_khan"
}
```

- `/symbol/` will search and replace only lines containing `symbol`

Comment: `sed -r '/symbol/ s/([a-z])([A-Z])/\1_\L\2/g' | awk '/^\{*[[:blank:]]*"symbol[s]?"[[:blank:]]*:/{ $0=tolower($0);}1''' `I used this

Comment: can you check now?